# $G=\{f_n(x):n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups, permutations

Define $f_n(x)=x+n \;\;\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $G=\{f_n:n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

I proved that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_\mathbb{R}$ ($f_n$ is a permutation of $\mathbb{R}$), and now I am trying to show that $G$ is cyclic.

I figured that I could do this by finding a generator of $G$. Then I realized I don't understand too much about generators, so I want to see if this approach is correct:

$G=\langle x+m \rangle : m\in \mathbb{Z}$ because $\forall f_n\in G$ it is clear that $f_n(x+m)=f_{n+m}(x)\in G$.

Is this sufficient to prove $x+m$ is a generator? (Is it even a generator?)

If that isn't correct, I was thinking of showing that $x+1$ is a generator (the other integers could be unnecessary). Please steer me in the right direction here. Just hints please, no full solutions.

Comment: What does $G = \langle x + m\rangle : m \in \mathbb{Z}$ even mean?

Comment: Your second idea (looking at $f_1$) is a good one. If you think about it, $f_m$ generates the subgroup $\{f_{km}\}_{k \in \mathbb Z}$, which is not the entire set $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ for most $m$.

Comment: Sorry Michael, should've specified--my book uses the notation: $G=\langle a \rangle$ to say that $a$ is a generator of $G$.

Comment: Morgan: it does seem like a good idea. Is $f_1$ alone a generator of the entire group? I think it might be but I also think that I need to include $f_{-1}$ as a generator, to "move" in the negative direction. Is this a flawed approach to cyclic groups?

Comment: @Patrick: That's standard notation. However, it is not clear what you mean by $G = \langle x + m\rangle : m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Patrick: it's perfectly possible that $f_{-1}$ is also a generator (I'll leave this to you to check). However, this does not preclude the group being cyclic. After all, $\mathbb Z$ has two generators ($\pm 1$). Remember that a subgroup is [generated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group) by a set $S$ if every element of the subgroup can be written as a finite combination of elements  in $S$ and *the inverses of elements in* $S$. If you haven't already, it might be a good idea to think about the structure of this group -- what is the identity? What is the inverse of $f_m$?

Comment: Oh. What I was trying to say was $G=\langle f_{m} \rangle$ where $m\in \mathbb{Z}$. But looking at it now that's not correct. It would be correct to just fix $m=1$. So $G=\langle f_{1} \rangle$.

Comment: Morgan: I forgot that part about inverses in the definition of a generator! $f_1^{-1} = f_{-1}$ (I proved this on paper earlier), so the statement $G=\langle f_1 \rangle$ means that $f_{-1}$ is also a generator! Thank you.

Comment: And in response to identity and inverse: I showed that $\epsilon (x)=x$ and $f_n^{-1} =f_{-n}$

Comment: @Patrick it looks like you have this figured out =) For future reference, if you want to address a specific a user you should include @ followed by the username in your comment (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for more info). This way the person is notified (otherwise they might only see it if they revisit your question).

Comment: @MorganO I see. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a composition law, not just a set, for this to be a group.

For this to be a group (and a subgroup of $S_{\mathbb{R}})$ you probably wanted to define composition as $f_n,f_m \mapsto f_n \circ f_m$.

Then $f_n, f_m \mapsto (x + m) + n = x + (m+n) = f_{m+n}$.  This shows that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}^+$ so it must be cyclic.

Alternatively, you can show that $f_1 = x+1$ is a generator.  Any $f_n$ is obtained by composing $f_1$ with itself $n$ times, and any $f_{-n}$ is obtained by composing the inverse of $f_1$ with itself $n$ times.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the first point you brought up: would it be adequate just to phrase my subgroup proof differently by saying $\langle G , \circ \rangle$ is a subgroup of $S_{\mathbb{R}}$?

Comment: $S_\mathbb{R}$ is the group of bijective maps $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ under composition of maps.  To show $\{f_i\}$ is a subgroup, you have to show 1.) that all $f_i$ are bijective maps of the real line to itself, 2.) that $\{f_i\}$ is closed under composition, and 3.) that the identity map $x \mapsto x$ is in $\{f_i\}$.  All of these are required to have a subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

$x+m$ is not an element of $G$. Perhaps what you meant to say is that $f_m$ is a generator for any $m$.

But that is not true either. For example, how can you get $f_1$ by composing $f_2$ with itself?